# Multiple type predicates in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a case where I'm frequently checking both the value of a boolean and another union type together. While they're logically connected and could hypothetically just check one, I need to check both so the TS compiler knows both types.

```js
let multiple: boolean
let value: Array<string> | string 
...
if (multiple && isArray(value)) {
  // TS knows multiple === true and value is an Array
}
```

Is there a way to write a type checking function where the type predicate asserts multiple values?

Something like this:

```js
// Not valid Typescript
function isMulti (
  multi: boolean, 
  value: Array<string> | string
): (multi is true) && (value is Array<string>) {
  return multi && isArray(value)
}
```

In most cases I can get by with just checking `isArray`, but there are cases where I want to reuse a check like the one above. Is this possible?

---

In response to @kaya3:

To give a more accurate use case, I have something similar to the following:

I could assign `multiple` and `value` to an object with a DiscriminatedUnion type, but that adds more complexity than I think this needs.

```js
type ValueType<M extends boolean> = M extends true ? Array<string> : string;

interface PropTypes<M extends boolean> {
  multiple: M,
  // more properties
}

type DiscriminatedUnion = {
  multiple: true,
  value: Array<string>
} | {
  multiple: false,
  value: string
}

function myFunction<M extends boolean>({
  multiple
}: PropTypes<M>) {

  let value: ValueType<M>;

  // ... later

  if (multiple) {
    // TS will not assert the type of `value` here
  }

  // Trying discriminated union
  // TS Error: Type '{ multiple: boolean; value: string | string[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ multiple: false; value: string; }'
  let obj: DiscriminatedUnion = {
    multiple,
    value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It isn't currently possible to solve your problem this way; @jcalz helpfully notes that there is an open [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26916) for it. That said, your problem is probably better solved in a different way.

For pretty much any question like "I have these two values, how can I tell Typescript their types are related?", the answer is to put them together as properties in an object. Then you can make the object's type a discriminated union, so that a test on one of the properties can narrow the type of the whole object.

```
type DiscriminatedUnion =
    | {multiple: false, value: string}
    | {multiple: true, value: string[]}

declare let obj: DiscriminatedUnion;

if(obj.multiple) {
    // here, obj.value is narrowed to string[]
    obj.value
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgZwMYCc4Fs4DsCGwIAmAqlnAPZZQC8AUFPVAD5QDe6ArgDbBxicQAuKADMcnBBAA0UAG5j2gqAmBosAcwC+dBszZcefRSoXS5nBUOWq1AbQC6WmgQhJOOFNH7AoZAEYArIXhkNExcfGJSCgBuGho4YQAKP38AOg5uXn4ASlZtegB6AqgACwgPaRTUswUoRChcFBQyAHdCKGAyJRVsWzt8nwDq+QgaLSA)

Comment: Yeah, the question is ostensibly about https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26916 or the like, but the actual use case is asking for discriminated unions.

Comment: Thanks! I added a bit more detail to the question. This solution would work, but involves some seemingly redundant work

Comment: @AdamMThompson Well yes, your edit to the question still has two separate values in different variables, instead of one object. You also didn't actually use a discriminated union type.

Comment: Sorry, should've added more there. I tried using a union there, but the TS compiler still complains since `value` could be either `string | Array<string>`